# Mi dev app is closed automatically

Tags: ios, xcode

When I exported a test app with xcode, in a development iphone, the application can work fine, or maybe afterwards it just does not start anymore, it happens to me with all the app that I have installed on an iphone.

My account does not have a paid developer license yet.

In summary.
I compile the application in a physical iphone, and after the cable is no longer connected, the application may no longer boot until I reinstall it with xcode, because it is a test.

Can help me please.

Comment: Do you see the icon on your phone? What happens when you try and open it?

Comment: If you have a free membership then apps need to be re-installed every few days.

Comment: Yes, is for the membership free. Thanks